# How to decrease regex computational time

Tags: regex

I'm making regular expression to find chosen log messages from Graylog. The problem is I can use just one regular expression for variety of messages. So I made regex:

```
^<189>.*Authenticate\sfail.*
```

but it is so computational heavy. There are usernames, IPs, etc. in these messages so I got not many possibilities how to get rid off that recursive part. So is it better to use

```
.*
```

or should I try to find as many describing string in messages as possible? In short, is regex:

```
^<189>.*UserName=.*Authenticate\sfail.*
```

better for computational performance than:

```
^<189>.*Authenticate\sfail.*
```

Comment: Could you post your regex and a pair of log lines as an example to regex101? One line should pass, another one should fail.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Sorry, I need it for work and got private information in these logs. But as an example, I got about 4k of log messages in a minute, about 300 of them contains string "Authenticate" and half of them contains "UserName=<username>" and the second half contains "UserName=host/<username>"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case,

```
^<189>.*Authenticate\sfail.*
```

would be faster.

You can use [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/) website to check how many steps were needed to run the regular expression. Paste your log into Test string field, play around and find a solution that needs as few steps as possible.